# Adding a background to current page menu item

Tags: css, html-lists

Should look like this:
[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/0ad52be5832d281682573c506096ae60.png))</sub>

My attempt

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="container">
   <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>
      <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#"><li class="current">Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Forums</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Donate</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Vote</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I use Current class for the current page background.

Added the header

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 86px;
background-image: url("../img/gradient.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-bottom: solid 1px #a2a2a2;
}
```

Floated menu to right, made it display inline and centered the text

```
.menu {
float: right;
padding: 2.7%;

}
.menu  a{
color: #1e1e1e;
}
.menu  a:hover{
color: #5e5e5e;
}

.menu li {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Now the part of the current background

```
.current {
background-image: url("../img/hoverdiamond.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 78px;
height: 36px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
color: white;
}
```

Result:

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/f3d859b9a5868de3d58c07b71eb3d1d6.png))</sub>

Can you see theres a big space between the current and other items? How do I remove this? make it equal to others spaces.

Things I tried:

Adding position relative

result:
Menu item 'current' goes over the menu item 'forums'

I could not find any other way to do so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following HTML:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="container">
      <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</li></a>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

With the following amends to your CSS:

```
.menu {
    float: right;
    padding: 2.7%;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu  a{
    color: #1e1e1e;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu  a:hover{
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.current {
    background-image: url("../img/hoverdiamond.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
}
```

Your HTML was structured incorrectly ... you shouldn't be placing the `<li>` elements inside the anchor elements.

You also don't need to have `display: inline;` on the list items, as they are floated left anyway, they should already be inline.

In future, you may want to check that your HTML is valid using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it should explain any errors in your HTML and how you can fix them.

Let me know if the above doesn't fix it and I'll happily have another look.

**EDIT:** Forgot to also state that I removed the height and width on the current css declaration, that was unnecessary, and almost definitely causing the spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width` on `.current`. That is what's adding the extra spacing.

If you don't want to change that, change the spacing on the the adjacent li:

```
.current + li {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Here is a simplified demo of what you are trying to accomplish. Learn from it:

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    float: right;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}

.current {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');
}
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tzunZ/)

Comment: tried removing, but now it only shows half of the current background image instead of the full image.

Comment: That's because your html is invalid. Structure it like this: `<ul><li><a href="">Home</a></li></ul>`, you can't have links as direct descendants of an unordered list.

Comment: Nothing really changes, what is that + selector?

Comment: the `+` is called the adjacent selector, it only select the first `<li>` after an element with a `current` class (in the example above)

Comment: I hope that makes sense, you can see a working demo here: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/840_cssSelectors/selectors/adjacent.html

Comment: Frankly, what you are trying to do is quite simple—you shouldn't need any advanced selectors. I would recommend starting from scratch and understanding where all the spacing is coming from. I've created a minimal example and includes everything you need to modify to build your own.